# Keeping Donuts fresh

Tags: doughnuts

Is there a way to preserve donuts and sell them in retail packaging, similar to how you would buy chips and cookies at the supermarket. I see Entenmann sells packaged donuts but I'm curious to know how they are able to maintain freshness. Any thoughts

Comment: Can you be more specific about the type of doughnut you're trying to sell? Most of the shelf-stable ones I see are cake-type doughnuts, which (due to their structure) tend to last longer in general... "Doughnuts" is a broad swath of products, please tell us what you're asking about more specifically.

Comment: I'm trying to produce a traditional donut mixed with protein that can be packaged and sold at retailers, I am not trying to do the traditional brick and mortar approach where you make them fresh. So any help would be appreciated as to what measures can be taken to preserve the taste and shelf life of a donut (cake or fried)

Comment: Cake doughnuts are still fried... they're simply a different type of batter. Yes, there's a movement of "baked doughnuts" for home cooks but despite the name, in general, cake doughnuts are cooked the same way as yeast doughnuts... they just have a  totally different structure...

Answer (score 3):

- Instead of fresh eggs, use powdered egg yolks.
- Make sure any oils you use are high in saturated fats, such as palm or soybean oil — and use their hydrogenated forms wherever possible.
- Replace some of the flour with polysorbate thickening agents and gums of xanthan, guar, and cellulose.
- Add moisturizing agents such as glycerin.
- Finally, be sure to include one or more chemical preservatives — potassium sorbate, for example.

Reference: [Entenmann's Donuts List of Ingredients](http://www.netgrocer.com/pd/Entenmanns-Donuts/Assorted-With-Frosted/20-50-oz/072030013879/)

Comment: Funny how Entenmann's doesn't list the ingredients on their site, only the nutritional info.